# Personalizar mensaje de error al no cargar webview por no tener internet en Fragment

Tags: android-fragment, webview

Tengo una aplicación que usa un `webview`, ahora lo que intento es que cuando no se tenga Internet no salga la clásica pantalla de error que contiene el link, quiero usar un mensaje personalizado.

Tengo algo de código, no me marca errores pero al querer iniciar la app se cierra automáticamente.

```
package mx.com.coraltours.coraltoursv1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;




public class ProximosViajesFragment extends Fragment {

    private static ConnectivityManager manager;


    public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }

        public ProximosViajesFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_personalizados, container, false);

            String url="http://www.google.com/";
            WebView view=(WebView) v.findViewById(R.id. WebViw);
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());// Agregamos un WebViewCliente, esto permite que se sigan ejecutando los links dentro de este WebView
            //view.loadUrl(url);

            /****************************************/
            if (isOnline(getActivity())) {
                url = "http://www.google.com/";
                view.loadUrl(url);
            } else {
                view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/pagina_error.html");
            }
            /****************************************/


            return v;
        }



}
```

---

Actualización, ya logre que muestre un mensaje de error en HTML cuando no tiene conexión, con el siguiente código:

package mx.com.coraltours.coraltoursv1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ProximosViajesFragment extends Fragment {

```
    public ProximosViajesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_proximosviajes, container, false);


        WebView view=(WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.WebViw);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());// Agregamos un WebViewCliente, esto permite que se sigan ejecutando los links dentro de este WebView

        // Comprueba la conexión a Internet
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        // Si hay conexión a Internet la variable hayConexion es verdadera
        boolean hayConexion = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();

        // Si hay conexión a Internet se carga la Url, si no hay conexión a
        // Internet se carga el mensaje de error.
        if (hayConexion) {
            String url="http://www.app.coraltours.com.mx";
            view.loadUrl(url);
        } else {

            String errorHtml = "<html>" +
                    "<head></head>" +
                    "<body>" +
                    "    <h3>Se requiere acceso a internet para ver este contenido</h3>" +
                    "</body></html>";

            view.loadData(errorHtml, "text/html", null);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, ahora el problema es cuando esta conectado pero sin internet o por ejemplo si quieres acceder con una red de un hotel o restaurante, esta te aparece en vez del mensaje de error que pograme.

Lo que busco es un método que compruebe la conexión a esa pagina y sino puede conectarse con ella o con google pues de el mensaje de error que yo programe.

Comment: ya logre que muestre en HTML cuando no se tiene conexion con el siguiente codigo

Comment: Esto se pregunto anteriormente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386238/verificar-conexi%c3%b3n-a-internet-en-android-studio/386343#386343

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
try {
    view.loadUrl(url);
} catch (Exception e) { // o la exception que sea
    view.loadData(errorHtml, "text/html", null);
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que solo contienen código se consideran de baja calidad ¿Podrías tratar de dar una explicación más detallada de por que tu respuesta a es válida?

Comment: Como indican otros usuarios, las respuestas que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad y no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita la respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué es lo que hace este código? ¿cómo soluciona el problema? ¿dónde iría dentro del código de la pregunta? Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás tu primera medalla).