# Verificar conexión a internet en android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo una app realizada con un Webview, pero necesito que cuando el celular no cuente con una conexión a internet esta muestre una pantalla de error en vez del típico error que no se puede acceder a la pagina del navegador.

Probé de muchas maneras pero en todas las verificaciones que hago siempre me toma como que tengo conecciòn por mas de que apague los datos y el wifi.

Algo de lo que probe:

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

} else {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: La clase NetworkInfo es obsoleta, usa la clase NetworkCapabilities, agregue respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar [conexiòn a internet usa el mètodo indicado en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3314/95):

```
public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivityManager != null) {
           NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
            if (capabilities != null) {
                if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR");
                    return true;
                } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI");
                    return true;
                }  else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET");
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;

}
```

**Mostrar pagina web al no tener conexión a internet.**

Primeramente debes crear el directorio `/assets` en tu proyecto y guardar ahí tu archivo `.html` "local", el cual se mostrará cuando no se tenga conexión a internet.

[Como poner y mostrar un archivo html en mi proyecto de android studio?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/82505/como-poner-y-mostrar-un-archivo-html-en-mi-proyecto-de-android-studio)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para detectar conectividad, requieres los permisos:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

---

Este sería un ejemplo, que cargaría el html llamado `mypage.html` almacenado en el directorio `/assets` de tu proyecto en caso de no existir conectividad, de otra forma se mostrará la url `https://es.stackoverflow.com/`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (isOnline(getApplicationContext()) {
            //Existe conexion, muestra pagina.
            webView.loadUrl("https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111923/verificar-internet-app-android-studio");
        } else {
            //*NO EXISTE CONEXION.
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mypage.html");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, sabes que probé también esa solución, pero es como que la pasa de largo, tenga o no tenga conexión es como que siempre detecta que tengo.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, sabes que probé también esa solución, pero es como que la pasa de largo, tenga o no tenga conexión es como que siempre detecta que tengo.asumo que ya es otro problema, no quiero re hacer el proyecto por que ya lo tengo en el play store, pero no se me ocurre mas nada.

Comment: Estas seguro que " por mas de que apague los datos y el wifi "  te dice que tiene conexión? recuerda que tienes que esperar unos segundos a que apague o encienda la antena.

Comment: sisi , inclusive genere el apk y lo probe en un celu.